# Whats wrong with my jQuery Code for RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UserControl "Day" that is repeated 5 times in another UserControl for 5 weekdays in a week that means each day 1 UserControl. And in this UserControl has RadioButtonList rdlAmountSlot is repeated 4 times with the below data

```
rdlAmountSlot_0 - Amount1 --- (1 - 100)
rdlAmountSlot_1 - Amount2 --- (100 - 1000)
rdlAmountSlot_2 - Amount3 --- (1000 - 10000)
rdlAmountSlot_3 - Amount4 --- (10000 - 100000)
```

I used the below code for confirmation from the user

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^='rdlAmountSlot_'][type='radio']").change(function () {
        var radioBtnId = this.id;
        var $this = $(this);
        radconfirm('Are you sure you want to select this slot?', function(arg){
            if (arg == true) {
                $find('<%= FindControl("txtAmount").ClientID %>').set_value("");
            }    
            else {
                $this.siblings('input').prop('checked',true);
                var rdlAmountSlot = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);
                rdlAmountSlot.checked = false;
                $this.prop('checked', false);
            }
        }, 300, 100,"");
    });
});
```

**The above code is throwing confirmation box for 5 times. What could be the reason and how to resolve it?**

**UPDATE**

Below is my markup code for each day

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDayView" runat="server">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlAmountSlot" CssClass="radio1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below is the markup for 5 days

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMonday" runat="server" >
        <uc1:My ID="MyMonday" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
        </td>
        <td>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlTuesday" runat="server" >
        <uc1:My ID="MyTuesday" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>

        </td>
        <td>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlWednesday" runat="server" >
        <uc1:My ID="MyWednesday" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>

        </td>
        <td>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlThursday" runat="server" >
        <uc1:My ID="MyThursday" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>

        </td>
        <td>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFriday" runat="server" >
        <uc1:My ID="MyFriday" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
```

This is the code similar to rdlAmountSlot

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability" class="radio1" border="0" style="color: #004B59; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial, Sans-serif; text-align: justify">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL01" disabled="disabled" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_0">Slot 0</label></span></td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL02" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_1">Slot 1</label></td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL03" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_2">Slot 2</label></td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MyAvailability$MyAvailabilityMonday$rdlAvailability" value="AVL04" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyAvailability_MyAvailabilityMonday_rdlAvailability_3">Slot 3</label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: probably `$this.prop('checked', false);` calls `change` event

Comment: A big "No" for this. I have commented the whole else code and still it is repeated 5 times.

Comment: If you have 5 sets of 4 radio buttons with same ids maybe that is causing the problem. Try leaving 3 sets of 4 radio buttons and see if it repeats 3 times. In that case just add different class attributes to them and change your $("[id^='rdlAmountSlot_'][type='radio']") selector accordingly so it's more precise.

Comment: `$find('<%= FindControl("txtAmount").ClientID %>').set_value("");` may call `change` too

Comment: Can you post your HTML with all 5 controls so we can try it on JS fiddle?

Comment: Updated my Question with the mark up for each day and in turn for 5 days

Comment: Can you please attach the generated HTML for 5 days?

Comment: This is very huge code for jsFiddle. Only for Monday, it comes to 16 pages. Can you please guide me on how to check it in jsFiddle?

Comment: WE need to check it in JS Fiddle since you have the code, YOU need to debug it in browser Development Tools.

Comment: Added the code similar to rdlAmountSlot in the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be if you try with `each` it would work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^='rdlAmountSlot_'][type='radio']").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function(){
            var radioBtnId = this.id;
            var $this = $(this);
            radconfirm('Are you sure you want to select this slot?', function(arg){
                if (arg == true) {
                    $find('<%= FindControl("txtAmount").ClientID %>').set_value("");
                }    
                else {
                    $this.siblings('input').prop('checked',true);
                    var rdlAmountSlot = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);
                    rdlAmountSlot.checked = false;
                    $this.prop('checked', false);
                }
            }, 300, 100,"");
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: With each it is repeating 4 times now